# Finitely generated group every 2-generated subgroup of which is finite

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I know of Tarski monsters and the Burnside Problem. I would like to know if there is an infinite finitely generated group $G$ such that for any $g$ and $h$ in $G$, the subgroup generated by $\{g,h\}$ is finite.

I am also interested in related questions:

- For which $(m,n)$ does there exist an infinite $m$-generated group every $n$-generated subgroup of which is finite?
- For which $(m,n,k)$ does there exist an infinite $m$-generated group every $n$-generated subgroup of which has cardinality at most $k$?

Thank you.

Comment: M. Ershov, *Golod-Shafarevich groups: a survey*. Internat. J. Algebra and Computation, vol. 22 (2012)

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks for pointing out this paper. I have skimmed through it: it does not solve any of these questions, does it?

Comment: Did you see theorem 3.3 in that paper? I think it answers at least your 2nd question.

Comment: And your first question, of course. A look at details of the proof can give you some estimates for the last question. I doubt there is a complete answer for that one.

Comment: It seems to me that Theorem 3.3 only answers the first question. Golod constructs an infinite $d$-generated $p$-group, such that every $d-1$-generated subgroup is nilpotent, but the nilpotency length of the subgroups is unbounded.

Comment: I think it's clear, looking at the proof of 3.3, that one may realize any $(m,n)$. Just take the generator size $|X|=m$ instead of $d$, and kill iterated commutators of all subsets of size $n$ so that the corresponding Golod-Shafarevich inequality holds. However, the size of the finite $n$-generated subgroups will likely be unbounded.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if somebody answers the question at this stage!

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta I don't know if there was a misunderstanding with Moishe Cohen, but if so, let me mention that when he speaks of first and second questions, it is out of three: the second question is not the last but the middle one.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I suggest you mention Theorem 3.3 of this article as an answer and I validate it. If someone solves the third question, then I will consider this new contribution to be the answer. But given its title, the question should be considered to be settled. By the way, does the paper prove that for every d, there is a k such that the question (d,d-1,k) has a positive answer?

Comment: @IanAgol Theorem 3.3 solves the (d,d-1)-case, and solving (d,d-1) implies solving (d,n) for n<d-1 (just taking the same group), so "we don't even have to look at the proof".

Comment: @user56097 Good point!

Comment: @Moishe Cohen: Sorry, i only thought about the two bulleted questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions 1 and 2 are answered by Golod's theorem, see Theorem 3.3 in 
the survey:

M. Ershov, [Golod-Shafarevich groups: a survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0490v1.pdf). Internat. J. Algebra and Computation, vol. 22 (2012).

Namely, for every $d\ge 2$ there exists an infinite $d$-generated group such that every $d-1$-generated subgroup is finite.

(He even gets a finite $p$-group for the given prime number $p$ but this is irrelevant.)

As for the last question, I am not sure, most likely it is unknown. I suggest to ask Ershov directly.

Comment: This is also true for $d = 1$.

Comment: Aren't all 0-generated groups finite?